# Program hangs after retrieving 100 rows containg CLOB

Tags: java, h2

I am retrieving one text column (CLOB) from a table in a "remote" H2 database (actually on a local drive, but using tcp to access it) and after retrieving the first 100 rows the program hangs on retrieving the next row of the result set.  If, on the other hand, I access the same database as an embedded database, there is no problem.  If I try to display the table's rows using H2's console application accessing the database using the Server (i.e. tcp) method, then I get the following error message:

```
IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: org.h2.message.DbException: The object is already closed [90007-164]"; 
"lob: null table: 14 id: 1" [90031-164] 90031/90031
```

Here is the program.  If I uncomment out the call that sets the system property, the program works.  I have also tried retrieving the column using a character stream or simply a call to getString, controlled by constant USE_STREAM.  There is no difference in the results:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Jdbc4
{
    private static final boolean USE_STREAM = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //System.setProperty("h2.serverResultSetFetchSize", "50");
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/file:C:/h2/db/test/test;IFEXISTS=TRUE", "sa", "");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "select select_variables from ipm_queues";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            int count = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                ++count;
                String s;
                if (USE_STREAM) {
                    Clob clob = rs.getClob(1);
                    Reader rdr = clob.getCharacterStream();
                    char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    int len;
                    while ((len = rdr.read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length)) != -1)
                        sb.append(cbuf, 0, len);
                    rdr.close();
                    s = sb.toString();
                    clob.free();
                }
                else
                    s = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println(count + ": " + s);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the DDL for creating the table (you can see it was originally a MySql table):

```
CREATE TABLE `ipm_queues` (
    `oid` bigint NOT NULL,
    `queue_id` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `store_id` bigint NOT NULL,
    `creation_time` datetime NOT NULL,
    `status` bigint NOT NULL,
    `deleted` bigint NOT NULL,
    `last_mod_time` datetime NOT NULL,
    `queue_name` varchar(128),
    `select_variables` text,
    `where_clause` text,
    `from_table` varchar(128),
    `order_by` varchar(256),
    `from_associate_table` varchar(256),
    `from_view` varchar(128)
);

ALTER TABLE ipm_queues
    ADD CONSTRAINT ipm_queues_pkey PRIMARY KEY (oid);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ipm_queues_key_idx ON ipm_queues(queue_id, store_id);

CREATE INDEX ipm_queues_str_idx ON ipm_queues(store_id);
```

Comment: Could you also post the code you have used to read the data? The error message "The object is already closed" sounds like an unexpected sequence of JDBC calls (I'm not saying incorrect, just unexpected). Without seeing the application code it's hard to say where the problem is.

Comment: "The object is alread closed" is an error message produced by the H2 Console application when you enter the query:

Comment: select * from ipm_queues; (the error message is NOT from any of my code)

Comment: Is the source and DDL proving to be helpful?  Anyone still looking into this?  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I understand the the cause of the hang.  I investigated the simplest case of using a h2.serverResultSetFetchSize value of 600, which is greater than the 523 rows I know that I have.  As I mentioned, I can retrieve the first 3 rows (single CLOB column) okay and then I either hang on the retrieval of the 4th row or I get a "The object is already closed" exception.

It turns out that the actual string comprising the first three columns seem to be rather short in length and method getInputStream in class org.h2.value.ValueLobDb has the data already and simply returns a ByteArrayInputStream constructed on this data.  The 4th row's data is still on the server side and so an actual RemoteInputStream has to be built to process fetch the data from the server-side LOB.

Here's what seems to be the problem:  Class org.h2.server.TcpServerThread is caching these LOBs in in instance of a SmallLRUCache.  This cache seems to be designed to maintain only the least recently referenced LOBs!!!  The default size of this cache is given by system property h2.serverCachedObjects, which defaults to 64, whereas the default fetch size is 100.  So even if I had not overridden the default h2.serverResultSetFetchSize property, if all of my rows had sufficiently large columns requiring cached LOBs, any fetch size > 64 would cause the LOB representing the first row to be flushed out of the cache and I would not even be able to retrieve the first row.

An LRU cache seems to be the wrong structure for holding LOBs that are in an active result set.  Certainly having a default cache size that is less than the default fetch size seems less than ideal.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug and should be fixed in the next version of H2.

Comment: I just re-tested with 1.3.166 using the H2 Console to retrieve the rows from ipm_queues and it still fails: SELECT * FROM IPM_QUEUES;
IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: org.h2.message.DbException: The object is already closed [90007-166]"; "lob: null table: 465 id: 55034" [90031-166] 90031/90031 (Help).  In this case each row has more than one column that is a CLOB, so simply increasing the size of the cache does not work.  I think you will have to come to the realization that A LRU CACHE CANNOT POSSIBLY BE THE RIGHT DATA STRUCTURE FORT THIS FUNCTIONALITY.

Comment: you are right, it will not work in all cases. A better solution would be nice. Patches are welcome :-)

Comment: I'd like to discuss this further offline. If you are interested, you can reach me at ronaa@optonline.net.

Comment: @Thomas Mueller : I'd like to discuss this further offline. If you are interested, you can reach me at ronaa@optonline.net.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably give more details, but did you check your network connection? Maybe your database server is blocking connections (or network connections) as soon as they try to fetch too much data. This could be a "sort of" protection.

Comment: The table has 523 rows.  When I started the application specifying system property h2.serverResultSetFetchSize with a value of 600, it hung after retrieving just 3 rows!  When I reran specifying this property with a value of 1, it no longer hung!  Values up to 87 seem to work OK.  A value of 88 hung after 88 rows were returned.

Comment: Yohann, I am not sure what you mean by "checking my network connections".  I am connecting to "localhost" and my "database server" is just a vanilla H2 install, with which I have very little experience.  I should be able to retrieve all 523 rows of this table, and I can by changing s system parameter that I don't fully understand.

Comment: I don't mean there is a network issue. What I mean is that the server may hang the jdbc connection when it considers it has to send too much data.